# jQuery Validations plugin- add delay to spinner to prevent quick flash

Tags: jquery, ajax, spinner, client-side-validation

Im using jQuery validation plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation to do some client side validations.

I have a remote validation to check whether a username is available in the database, and I would like my spinner to hang about for maybe a second longer than the request will take, to prevent the sudden flash of the spinner appearing/disappearing when the responce is very quick.

The code I am using to handle the spinner is as follows:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxStart.mine", function() {
  $('#myloader').show();
});

$(document).bind("ajaxStop.mine", function() {
  $('#myloader').hide();
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add "delay" to hide animation

```
 $(document).bind("ajaxStart.mine", function() {
     $('#myloader').show();
   });

    $(document).bind("ajaxStop.mine", function() {
     $('#myloader').delay(5000).hide('slow');
   });
```

Comment: Wouldn't you delay before you hide it?

Comment: Mikhali is right, the delay should be before the hide: '$('#myloader').delay(5000).hide('slow');

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mine").ajaxStart(function() {
  $('#myloader').show();
});
```

is probably the correct one. Do the same with first one